# Multiple levels of "has many" relationship

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to achieve a structure where e.g. an Organisation has many Departments, and where Departments has many Persons.

I've set up my model structure like this:

**Organisations**

```
<?php

class Organisation extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
            'Department' => array(
                'className' => 'Department',
                'foreignKey' => 'organisations_id'
            )
        );
}
```

**Departments**

```
<?php

class Department extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
            'Person' => array(
                'className' => 'Person',
                'foreignKey' => 'departments_id'
            )
        );
}
```

**Persons**

```
<?php

class Person extends AppModel {

}
```

Then I have a controller like this:

```
<?php

class OrganisationsController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');


    public function index() {
        $this->set('organisations', $this->Organisation->find('all'));
    }

}
```

When I print out $organisations I get an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Organisation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [created] => 2013-01-03 16:02:47
                )

            [Department] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [created] => 2013-01-03 16:02:47
                            [organisations_id] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'm new to both PHP and CakePHP, but wouldn't you expect the Person array to be included in the Organisation array? And if not, is there another way to achieve a structure like the one described above (Organisation->Department->Person)?

Any hints on how to go about this is highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive)

Or you could make use of the [containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

But please have a look at the result. When using recursive you can get a lot of data you don't want! So please be careful and select the fields you actually need!

**Recursive**

You would get something like:

```
<?php

class OrganisationsController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');


    public function index() {
        $this->Organisation->recursive = 2; # or -1, 0, 1, 2, 3
        $this->set('organisations', $this->Organisation->find('all'));
    }
}
```

You could also declare this in the find itself like so:

```
$this->set('organisations', $this->Organisation->find('all' array(
        'recursive' => 2 # or -1, 0, 1, 2, 3
    )
));
```

**Containable**

```
class Organisation extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Department' => array(
            'className' => 'Department',
            'foreignKey' => 'organisations_id'
        )
    );

    $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

Now in your controller you can do something like:

```
$this->set('organisations', $this->Organisation->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array('User')
    )
));
```

But as always, there are many roads leading to Rome. So please read the books very carefully!

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.htm
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: That did it, although I have to look into how I filter the result. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @timkl Filtering the result can be easily done by specifying the fields you need. Like so in your find: `'contain' => array('User' => array('fields' => array('the', 'fields', 'you', 'need')))`. I learned this best by simply logging the find result in the debug log and simply mess around with the query. You will get the hang of it after a while. I have to mention though. I am still messing around with the contains sometimes. They can be quite confusing when working with all those methods mixed up :)

Comment: @Jelmer Brilliantly explained :)

Answer (score 1):

[Recursive](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/daveym/2011/05/08/array_structures_the_recursive_property_and_the_set_class) function will do it for you.

Just in OrganisationsController index function , try doing like below.

```
  $this->Organisation->recursive = 2;
  $this->set('organisations', $this->Organisation->find('all'));
```

**Note:** Recursive may affect your performance , you can use [unbind](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/TommyO/2006/12/06/keeping-bindmodel-and-unbindmodel-out-of-your-controllers) method to get rid of it by just fetching the data you want.

Comment: Didn't see your answer. Kudos for you as well :)